# How to mantain 2 very similar projects with GIT?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

look, i have a BitBucket repository, and i manage it using SourceTree (it's easier for me using a GUI). i've been using it for a while but in a very basic way because i'm VERY FAR from an expert on Git and i was the only one developing that project. 
There's a new developer, and we need to have 2 very similar (almost identical) projects.

I want to keep the projects apart but sharing most of it's features, because they will be used in 2 different companies. Most of the code is going to be useful for both companies, but some features are exclusive to one company or the other.

For example: The login and permissions code is useful for both projects, but a feature to control production times is only useful to one of the companies.

What would be the best way to do this? a fork using pull requests?  a branch for each project?

Comment: Branch for each company sounds the way to go to me.

Comment: Hard to give an exact answer.  Let's say the product is a webpage, and each company would have slightly different features.  Then, you could have a `master` branch containing code for _all_ features, and each company could have a branch/release where certain features are turned on or off.

Comment: Thank you for your answers... so, if i change something in the "common code branch" then i have to merge that branch to the "Company 1" and "Company 2" branches to update both projects??  but if i want to develop something for company 1 i do it directly on its branch... right??

Answer (score 0):

[Git branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) would be what you are looking for. Start the project with the minimal codebase for both companies, then branch twice. If the projects are separate enough you can consider using [Microservice Architecture](https://microservices.io/) e.g. creating a service for authentication in a separate project to your production times service.